# Jquery .load in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, css, jquery

I have a vertical left menu in my asp.net page.

using jquery .load,i try to load other aspx page in the midlle div(content div)

depending on the link click.Like this:

```
          $('#LeftMenu1_HyperLink1').live("click", function(event) {
             event.preventDefault();
            $("#ContentDiv").load("mypage.aspx");

        });
```

this solution doesn't work,i have followed the jquery doc.Do i should add some thing in mypage.aspx,all the examples i found i found googling don't work.

Can someone pls give me a working link or an example for that.

Comment: Define "doesn't work" - does the function fire? Look in Firebug's "Net" tab to see whether the request is made. Also, you are aware that `mypage.aspx` mustn't return a full HTML structure with `head` and `body, but only a snippet?

Answer (score 1):

You're embedding a full HTML document into a `<div>` element. The result will look like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
    .
    .
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <html>
                <head>
                .
                .
                </head>
                <body>
                .
                .
                </body>
            <html>
        </div>
    .
    .
    </body>
</html>
```

The browser won't be able to do anything with that. Try loading your page in an [`<iframe>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_iframe.asp) element instead of a`<div>`.

Answer (score 1):

The best thing you can do (short of only responding with the requested content) is have a container in there, like this:

```
<div id="ContentDiv">
  <div id="ContentInner">
  </div>
</div>
```

This is to prevent multiple IDs in the page when doing the [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/).  Since [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/) takes a selector you'd then use that to get the content, like this:

```
$('#LeftMenu1_HyperLink1').live("click", function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   $("#ContentDiv").load("mypage.aspx #ContentInner");
});
```

Now this loads *only* that inner `<div>` onto this page.

---

Some considerations to this approach you're taking:

- Scripts/styles in the `<head>` won't be loaded
- Be sure your `<form>` is *inside* that `<div id="ContentInner">`

Comment: Nick,Content div is not in mypage.aspx,it is in Default.aspx containg the vertical left menu.I want to load mypage.aspx into   ContentDiv when the user click a the left menu element(link).Is that possible?Thanks

Comment: @Cooly - you need some ID or class you can target in the page you're loading...otherwise you're loading *all* of that page.